# Фильтр для двух моделей Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

**Доброго дня!**
Как я могу создать фильтр по времени сразу для двух похожих моделей?

```
class Boat(models.Model)
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a Boat name")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time']

class Car(models.Model)
    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=140, help_text="Enter a Car name")
    company = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    time = models.TimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, editable=False, blank=True, null=True)

    def __str__(self):

        return self.name
        
    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-time']
```

**Заранее Спасибо!**

Comment: Вы бы поточнее описали задачу, а то непонятно что вы хотите получить.

Comment: @Stanislav например три последних созданных объекта, но не одной модели а двух.

Comment: Это? `Boat.objects.all()[:3].union(Car.objects.all()[:3])`